# C# Как изменить text label1

Tags: c#

Хочу написать мини программку для себя которая будет выводить информацию о ПК и его комплектующих. Хочется что бы при открытии программы текст в label2 менялся на значение которое выдаст Environment.ProcessorCount

```
    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = " ave ";
```

что бы не сразу при нажатии - а при открытии формы, хелпаните плез(

Comment: Ну добавь событие form onload.  И у лабела свойство content  а не text

Comment: @axmed2004 - Content это в WPF. Тут по сигнатуре метода понятно, что WinForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public имя вашей формы()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     label2.Text = Environment.ProcessorCount.ToString();
}
```

вам нужно записывать значение в ваш лейбл при инициализации формы

Comment: лучше, все-таки, не при инициализации, а в обработчике события Form_Load

Comment: @МаксЖуков смотря для каких целей. Не думаю, что информация о пк может как-то поменяться в процессе работы программы (может быть, это и возможно) :)

Comment: я думаю, когда ТС изучит этот вопрос более углубленно, начнет использовать Form_Load ))